# Why are these asp values not passed to code behind? (ASP & Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

This web form should feed into an access database. 
However it keeps saying stuff like " Field 'Exhibits.FirsNtame' cannot be a zero-length string." I know the code works because it will write to the database if I hard code in values. How do I get values to the variables in the code behind the page?

Here is the web page:

```
      <%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ScienceFair.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">


        <style type="text/css">
            .auto-style1 {
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>


    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
        <div id="RuleBreaker">
        <h2 class="auto-style1">Science Fair Registration</h2>
        <p class="auto-style1" >
            First Name:
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="FirsNtame" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="FirstName"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="FirsNtameValidator1" runat="server"
      ControlToValidate="FirsNtame"
      ErrorMessage="A first name is required."
      ForeColor="Red">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />

            Last Name:
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="LasNtame" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="LastName"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="LasNtameValidator2" runat="server"
      ControlToValidate="LasNtame"
      ErrorMessage="A last name is required."
      ForeColor="Red">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />

            Student Email Address:
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="StudentEmail" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="Email"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="StudentEmailValidator3" runat="server"
      ControlToValidate="StudentEmail"
      ErrorMessage="A Student Email is required."
      ForeColor="Red">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

             <br />
             <br />
            School:
             <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="School" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="SchoolValidator4" runat="server"
      ControlToValidate="School"
      ErrorMessage="Your school name is required."
      ForeColor="Red">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

             <br />
            Grade:
            <br />
                <asp:DropDownList id="Grade" runat="server" Width="86px">
                    <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>12</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="GradeValidator5" runat="server"
      ControlToValidate="Grade"
      ErrorMessage="A grade is required."
      ForeColor="Red">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

            <br />
                Teacher's Last Name (only):<br />
                <asp:TextBox id="Teacher" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="TeacherValidator6" runat="server"
      ControlToValidate="Teacher"
      ErrorMessage="A teacher last name is required."
      ForeColor="Red">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />

                Teacher E-mail:<br />&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TeacherEmail" runat="server" 
                    Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
                <br /> 

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="TeacherEmailValidator7" runat="server"
      ControlToValidate="TeacherEmail"
      ErrorMessage="A teacher email is required field."
      ForeColor="Red">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />

                <%-- Teacher Phone Number:<br />&nbsp;<asp:TextBox id="TPhone" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox> --%>
                <%-- Might put the above in later --%>
                Catagory :<br />&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList id="Catagory" runat="server" Width="212px">
                    <asp:ListItem>Behavorial &amp; Social Sciences</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Biochemistry &amp; Microbiology</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Botany</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Environmental Sciences</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Medicine &amp; Health</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Zoology</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Chemistry</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Computer Science</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Earth &amp; Space Sciences</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Engineering</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Mathematics</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Physics</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <br />

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="CatagoryValidator8" runat="server"
      ControlToValidate="Catagory"
      ErrorMessage="A catagory is required."
      ForeColor="Red">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />

                Exibit Title :<br />&nbsp;<asp:TextBox id="ExibitTite" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="ExibitTiteValidator9" runat="server"
      ControlToValidate="ExibitTite"
      ErrorMessage="A title is required."
      ForeColor="Red">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />

                Does your exhibit use electricity?<br />
                <%-- Possible issues here, may need to use 1 & 0 instead--%>
                <asp:DropDownList id="Electricity" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Yes">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="No">No</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />

     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="ElectricityValidator10" runat="server"
      ControlToValidate="Electricity"
      ErrorMessage="Does your computer use electricity?"
      ForeColor="Red">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />

        </p>
            <p class="auto-style1" >
                <asp:Button ID="SciFairSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
                <br />
                <br />
        </p>
        </div>

    </asp:Content>
```

Here is the aspx code behind the page:

```
 Imports System.Data.OleDb

    Partial Class _Default
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

        Protected Sub SciFairSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SciFairSubmit.Click
            'form data requests----------------------------------------------------------------------------C:\Users\NCG-PC\Webmastering\TamugSciFair13\WebSite1\Default1.aspx.vb

            Dim strName As String = If(Request.Form("FirsNtame"), "")
            Dim strLasNtame As String = If(Request.Form("LasNtame"), "")
            Dim strStudentEmail As String = If(Request.Form("strStudentEmail"), "")

            Dim strSchool As String = If(Request.Form("strSchool"), "")
            Dim numGrade As String = If(Request.Form("numGrade"), "")
            Dim strTeacher As String = If(Request.Form("strTeacher"), "")
            Dim strTeacherEmail As String = If(Request.Form("strTeacherEmail"), "")

            Dim strCatagory As String = If(Request.Form("strCatagory"), "")
            Dim strExibitTite As String = If(Request.Form("strExibitTite"), "")
            Dim strElectricity As String = If(Request.Form("strElectricity"), "")

            'Open Db Connection---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            Dim strSQL As String
            Dim dbconn As OleDbConnection = Nothing

            dbconn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" & Server.MapPath("\GalvestonScienceFair\App_Data\sf13.mdb"))
            dbconn.Open()

            'SQL actions ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO Exhibits (FirsNtame, LasNtame, StudentEmail, School, Grade, Teacher, TeacherEmail, Category, ExibitTite, Electricity) values (@FirsNtame, @LasNtame, @StudentEmail, @School, @Grade, @Teacher, @TeacherEmail, @Category, @ExibitTite, @Electricity)"
            Dim objcmd = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, dbconn)




            objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@FirsNtame", strName))
            objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@LasNtame", strLasNtame))
            objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@StudentEmail", strStudentEmail))

            objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@School", strSchool))
            objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Grade", numGrade))
            objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Teacher", strTeacher))
            objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@TeacherEmail", strTeacherEmail))

            objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Category", strCatagory))
            objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@ExibitTite", strExibitTite))
            objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Electricity", strElectricity))

            'Sets each parameter to "DBNULL" or "blank" if they are null/blank
            'objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@FirsNtame", If(strName, DBNull.Value)))
            For Each param As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter In objcmd.Parameters
                If param.Value Is Nothing Then
                    param.Value = DBNull.Value
                End If
            Next

            objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            'Close DB Connection
            dbconn.Close()
            Response.Write("Thank you for registering!")
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: Holy `FirsNtame` to `FirstName` copy & paste typo's batman!

Comment: That's a TON of code and markup to read through.  Could you pare it down to just the important snippets?

Comment: Why aren't you just using `FirsNtame.Text`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you add parameters do as below

```
objcmd.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParamName", YorTextBox.Text)
```

Comment: I'm new to visual basic so I'm not sure how to implement your pseudo-code.
JTorres: I did that on purpose.
GarrisonNeely: I want to put a string from the form into a variable:
Dim strSchool As String = If(Request.Form("strSchool"), "")